# PHP Login using a txt file

Tags: php, html, authentication

hello I am working on a project where i have to create a php login using a text file. I have the basic code laid out but when I put a username and password on file and try signing in, it does not work. I could really use some advise. thank you. The code below is my login php file.

```
<?php
session_start();
$User = $_GET["user"];
$Pass = $_GET["password"];

if (!strpos($User,"@")) {
   $User = $User . "@etown.edu";
}
$Validuser = false;
$_SESSION["user"] = $User;
$_SESSION["pass"] = $Pass;
$_SESSION["login"]= $Validuser;


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<?php
    print "<h2>Welcome $User</h2>";

$infile = fopen("account.txt","r");
      $entry = fgets($infile);
         while (!feof($infile)) {
        $array = explode(" ",$entry);
            if ($array[0] == $User){
           $name = $array[0];
           $code = $array[1];
           $code = substr($code,0,strlen($code)-1);
           }
            $entry = fgets($infile);
    }
print "Name: $name <br/>";
print "pass on file: $code <br />";

fclose($infile);
    if ($name==$User && $code==$Pass)
       $Validuser = true;
    $_SESSION["login"] = $Validuser;

    print "That's All!<br/>";

    if ($Validuser) {
        print "Welcome valid user<br/>";
}
    else {
         print "You are not a valid user.  Go become one first!";
         print '<script type="text/javascript">';
         print '   //document.location = "register.html";';
         print '</script>';

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your file? It could give you some useful insights

Comment: "..., it does not work." is not a valid problem description. What does not work? What is in the variables? What do you expect at certain points in the script and what is actually happening?

Comment: `$_GET["password"]`, oh, that's safe. Lordie, use a database and a 21st century password hashing function.

Comment: sorry, by it does not work i mean it is not logging me in. the print statements i have after the loop do not return any values for $name and $code

Comment: can i see your account.txt file content?

or take a look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205610/php-login-from-text-file

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: user in /home/jah/public_html/social/test.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: password in /home/jah/public_html/social/test.php on line 4
Welcome @etown.edu


Notice: Undefined variable: name in /home/jah/public_html/social/test.php on line 35
Name: 

Notice: Undefined variable: code in /home/jah/public_html/social/test.php on line 36
pass on file: 

Notice: Undefined variable: name in /home/jah/public_html/social/test.php on line 39
That's All!
You are not a valid user. Go become one first!

Comment: @TreyYetter That means you got something to debug. If `$name` and `$code` do not contain anything, the most likely thing is that they are not set. This means that your while-loop probably doesn't do what you expect it to do. Use `var_dump(..)` to dump the content of `$array` and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this

```
    $User = isset($_GET["user"]) ? $_GET["user"] : '';
    $Pass = isset($_GET["user"]) ? $_GET["password"] : '';
    $name ='';
    $code='';
```

i'm assuming your txt file is like this

```
ja@etown.edu 12345
ja2@etown.edu 12345
ja3@etown.edu 12345
```